# Escaping double quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
 facetsString += "<td><input type='checkbox' value=facetList[count].term>&nbsp;&nbsp;" + facetList[count].term +  " (" + facetList[count].count + ")" + "</td>";
```

I'm trying to give each checkbox a unique value `facetList[count].term`, but I don't know how to escape the double quotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape double quotes like this:

```
"string with \"double qoutes\""
```

The solution is:

```
facetsString += "<td><input type='checkbox' value=\"" + facetList[count].term + "\">&nbsp;&nbsp;" + facetList[count].term + " (" + facetList[count].count + ")" + "</td>";
```

The example provided would write `facetList[count].term` in the value attribute, and not the actual value of the variable.

Comment: facetsString+="<td><input type='checkbox' value=\"facetList[count].term\">&nbsp;&nbsp;"+facetList[count].term+  " (" + facetList[count].count + ")" + "</td>";

Comment: value should hav the array item facetList[count].term.. this one is inside a loop...bt im getting the code value="facetList[count].term"

Answer (score 5):

Just put a backslash in front of the double-quotes:

```
facetsString += "<td><input type='checkbox' value=\"facetList[count] ... \" /></td>"
```

Alternatively, you can wrap the outer in single quotes, and use double quotes for property values:

```
facetsString += '<td><input type="checkbox" value="facetList[count] ... " /></td>'
```