# JavaScript - Escape double quotes

Tags: jquery, json, replace

How do you escape double quotes if the JSON string is the following?

```
var str = "[{Company: "XYZ",Description: ""TEST""}]"
```

I want to escape the secondary double quotes in value *TEST*.

I have tried the following, but it does not work.

```
var escapeStr = str.replace(/""/g,'\"');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you constructing JSON by yourself rather than using `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: as a sidenote, the regular expression you were using is incorrect, it should be `str.replace(/"/g,'\"')`

Comment: Related: *[Escaping double quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241663/escaping-double-quotes-in-javascript)*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It should be:

```
var str='[{"Company": "XYZ","Description": "\\"TEST\\""}]';
```

First, I changed the outer quotes to single quotes, so they won't conflict with the inner quotes. Then I put backslash before the innermost quotes around `TEST`, to escape them. And I escaped the backslash so that it will be treated literally.

You can get the same result with use of a JSON function:

```
var str=JSON.stringify({Company: "XYZ", Description: '"TEST"'});
```

Comment: First example is still invalid though. JSON object keys must be double-quoted as well. Though, one should really use `JSON.stringify` for this.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice he left those quotes out.

Comment: I forgot to double quote the JSON object in my example.  I will try JSON.stringify. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here the inner quote is escaped and the entire string is taken in single quote.

```
var str = '[{ "Company": "XYZ", "Description": "\\"TEST\\""}]';
```

Comment: btw JSON object keys must be double-quoted as well.