# unescaping \" in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, escaping

I get a JSON object returned to me as follows:

```
result: {
 image: "..."
 title: "text text \"text\""
}
```

I am using underscore.js to render the template however when when it displays the title it includes the \" in the text.

e.g text text \"text\"

How can I unescape the the double quotes before displaying?

Thanks

Comment: That's not a real representation of the JSON object. The actual JSON must have `text text \\\"text\\\"` to produce the behavior you describe. The problem is that it's being escaped twice, and only (and correctly) unescaped once. Figure out where the second escaping is coming from.

Comment: That isn't a JSON object though. JSON is just text. They're aren't literals in JSON. There are literals in JavaScript Objects, but not JSON.

Comment: This is certainly not JSON. How are you retrieving the representation you posted? How is the data generated in the first place? If the output is `\"` then it means the string literally contains a \ . The proper way to fix that would be to fix the data generation/storage.

Comment: The JSON in the question is whats being returned to the browser. It might be possible that the string is being doubled escaped. Currently investigating that possibility. Thanks for the info all!

Comment: something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559625/javascript-escape-double-quotes

Comment: It look like the string was being double escaped. @meagar if you want to post your comment as an answer i will accept it. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

.replace can do it:

```
text = result.text.replace(/\\([\\"])/g, '$1');
```

Comment: I fix it. $1 is [\\"]

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559625/javascript-escape-double-quotes) might be helpful, but I see in your comments that you are getting exactly same data as you have mentioned, so:

```js
var result = { image: "...", title: "text text \"text\"" }

alert (result.title.toString().replace(/"/g, ''));
```