# How to pass a string with double quoutes as property in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I just tried to use code like below:

```
<editor init-text="String "Test""></editor>
```

But DOM breaks because of qoutes in given string.

How to avoid that problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Escape Double Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559625/javascript-escape-double-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quotes with a `\`

```
<editor init-text="String \"Test\""></editor>
```

Or mix single `'` and double `"` quotes

```
<editor init-text='String "Test"'></editor>
```

Comment: Single qoutes can help untill i face with single qoutes in a string too.
That's not working for me. Only &quot; entity works.

Comment: Or you can declare a string with tick quotes in `data()` and use `:init-text`. I.e. in template: `<editor :init-text="str"></editor>`. In `<script>`: `data() { return { str: \`String "Test" String 'Test'\` }; }`