# Escaping double quotes in JavaScript from a string in a variable

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, replace

I have these two scenarios:

---

```
console.log(('hello "friend" what\'s up?').replace(/\"/g, '\\"'));
```

I receive the expected result:

> hello "friend" what's up?

---

**But**, if I do this:

```
var val = 'hello "friend" what\'s up?';
val.replace(/\"/g, '\\"');
console.log(val);
```

I get...

> hello "friend" what's up?

*(the result needs to be `hello \"friend\" what's up?`)*

---

The only difference is that the second one uses an already created variable that contains the string. Why doesn't the second scenario actually replace the double quotes with `\"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Escaping double quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241663/escaping-double-quotes-in-javascript)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> The replace() method **returns a new string** with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.

You need to do `val = val.replace(/\"/g, '\\"');` so that you're assigning the new string returned by calling `replace` to your variable.

Comment: I feel stupid. Had my "jQuery" mode on, as in `$(this).attr('something', 'value');` Thank you!

Comment: Is it necessary to use regular expressions for simple substitutions of literal strings?

Answer (score 1):

Actually by doing

```
val.replace(/\"/g, '\\"');
```

You're not assigning the replaced value back to `val`. For that you will need:

```
val = val.replace(/\"/g, '\\"');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val.replace(/\"/g, '\\"');
```

In the above code you are not reassigning to `val`;

Try this to get the expected result.

```
val = val.replace(/\"/g, '\\"');
```