# Escape double quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I'm a student who has to deal with an intern hacking challenge. I'm that far that I'm able to insert JavaScript code.

My one and only problem...
I can't use single quotes since the firewall blocks it.

Double quotes are giving me an error because of double use:

```
<a id="bb" href="javaSCRIPT&colon;document.body.innerHTML = "lol"">clicks</a>
```

How can I use the above line of code, just like using single quotes?

```
<a id="bb" href="javaSCRIPT&colon;document.body.innerHTML = 'lol'">clicks</a>
```

(Try it in an empty HTML document, please.)

Comment: The `\ ` character should do it. So `innerHTML = \"lol\""`. Actually, if "&colon;" worked, then "&quot;" might also work.

Comment: @Katana314 backslashing didn't work &quot did work

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Escaping double quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241663/escaping-double-quotes-in-javascript)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you;

```
<a id="bb" href="javascript&colon;document.body.innerHTML=&quot;foo&quot;">clicks</a>
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/49ay5jwf/

Comment: @FitzOrPercy Maybe if you share the rules of the challenge we may be able to help further. Otherwise I have no way of knowing if any solution I offer will work for you.

Comment: Sorry :) Thx for your input! it worked.. I thought & quotes were disabled but they're not

Comment: I thought using document.body.innerHTML would've changed the homepage permanently (from the moment there is an 'onload') sadly enough it only goes to a new generated html page. Is there another way to do this without using 'onload'. I have no list of blocked features of the firewall so I can only test and check if I can get through

Comment: @FitzOrPercy I don't know I'm afraid :(

Comment: I think what's changing the page is the use of an `<a href>`. That's just a guess - if there's some way of making it a `<button onclick="...">` would that do it?

Comment: What is the explanation? What is the name of the encoding that takes place? Can you make this answer more comprehensible?

Comment: @PeterMortensen this is using [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Getting_started#Entity_references_Including_special_characters_in_HTML).